# .htaccess remove a parameter after pass

Tags: .htaccess

I have an htaccess file to redirect url as a parameter. It's working fine except sometimes it show parameter in url.
This is my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options -Indexes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:css|js|jpe?g|gif|png|ttf|eot|svg|woff|woff2)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

And this is examples of entry urls:

```
entry: test.com/mypath/ -> redirect: test.com/mypath/ (right)
entry: test.com/mypath/subpath -> redirect: test.com/mypath/subpath (right)
entry: test.com/mypath/subpath/ -> redirect: test.com/mypath/subpath/ (right)

entry: test.com/mypath -> redirect: test.com/mypath/?url=mypath (wrong)
```

it's showup like this: 
`test.com/mypath/?url=mypath`
just because not entered `/` at the end of url.
How to solve this?

Comment: could you be more precise

Comment: I have edited examples

Answer (score 0):

TO remove trailing backslash at the end of url, add this line at the top after RewriteEngine On, and it should work for you

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R] [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I'm not sure is it the problem I explained but it's not solved the problem I got.